# How to hide the wifi icon on the Status (Notification) bar

Tags: wi-fi, notification-bar

I read this question [How to hide status bar notification icons?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56020/how-to-hide-status-bar-notification-icons)

But i want to remove only the Wifi Icon in the Status bar of my Android Mobile.

How can i do this ?

Or Is there any app to do this ?

Note : I didn't root my device

Comment: I think it's impossible on no root devices